# Urllib not loading full response

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am using python 3 urllib to POST request on a website and although I am getting the response it is only showing a part of the html...this is code I am using:https://github.com/CyberChild/openCV/blob/master/stack_overflow.py

Comment: How do you know it's not the entire thing? Try loading the page in your browser without running javascript to confirm.

Comment: thats exactly what I don't want....I need the JavaScript to process the output and then show me the wepage...to get the results of specific students

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't include enough information in the post itself to help either answerers or future readers. Please include your code in your posts, preferably trimmed down to show just the problem you're seeing.  Please also include information about whatever troubleshooting you've already tried, as well as concrete details about the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. The name of the submit button is `txhSubmit`, but you typo'd it to `txhSunmit`
2. You are requesting the page with the form, instead of the page the form submits to.  Change the endpoint to `http://59.145.203.105/Login.asp`

---

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://59.145.203.105/Login.asp'
values = {'txtRoll' : '1305024',
          'txtEnroll' : '13139428723',
          'txhSubmit'  : 'Submit'
           }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
binary_data=data.encode()
req = urllib2.Request(url, binary_data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read().decode()
print the_page
```

Comment: I didn't quite catch you on the second point

Comment: You are sending your request to the page with the form.  The page with the form is capturing the same fields you are specifying in your request.  When you click the Submit button, it is sending your form data to the Login.asp page.  The form page itself does not do any processing of POST data.  It is the url in the "action" part of the form that processes the request.

Comment: tried changing url='http://59.145.203.105/Login.asp' nothing's changed

Comment: Did you change the name of the submit button?  I had to change the code a little because I am Phython2.x, but once I changed the submit button and the endpoint, it works fine.

Comment: yup did that, and what are you referring to as the end point?

Comment: Anyway if you do have the program working in Python2 can you give me the source code...I was actually intending to use the code with SL4A so Python2 would be a much better option